# Created nested Json in for loop

Tags: python, json

I want to create in python a Json file like bellow

```
{
  'Query': 'Pages',
  'items': [
    {
      'url': 'https://stackoverflow.com/',
      'Title': 'Stack Overflow Share',
      'Description': 'Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community for developers to learn, share​ ​their programming ​knowledge, and build their careers'
    },
    {
      'url': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page',
      'Title': 'Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia',
      'Description': 'Main page'
    }
  ]
}
```

However I am far from achieving this:

```
import json
response_json = {}

items = []
# This list bellow is generated in a for loop (with append to a list) if you have a suggestion how I could do this in a dictionary and use it in the for loop bellow
urls=["https://stackoverflow.com/", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"]
Title=["https://stackoverflow.com/", "Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia"]
Description=["Stack Overflow is the largest","Main page"]

for item in Dictornary_Maybe:
    items.append({"url" : item[url],
                     "Title" : Title,
                     "Description" : Description
                     )




response_json["items"] = items

with open('2result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(response_json, fp)
```

As you could see this is not, working and I don't know how to proceed further

Comment: General note, take a look at what `dict` (and here also `zip`) have to offer. I think the key thing here is creating / working with dicts. dumping that to `json` (or whatever) is just what comes at the end of the pipe.

Comment: As a more general consideration "parallel lists" (two or more lists matched by index) is a very brittle data structure. Change one of the lists and the mapping is broken. A list of dicts or tuples (actually just what you're trying to do for your json export) is a much saner data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do:

```py
import json

urls = ["https://stackoverflow.com/", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"]
Title = ["Stackoverflow", "Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia"]
Description = ["Stack Overflow is the largest", "Main page"]

# a bit of modification to get the items list of dictionaries:
keys = ['url', 'title', 'description']
items = [dict(zip(keys, [u, t, d])) for u, t, d in zip(urls, Title, Description)]

# create the output dict
d = {
      'Query': 'Pages',
      'items': items
    }

# make a pretty json string from the dict
d = json.dumps(d, indent=4)

# write the string to a txt file
with open(file, 'w') as fobj:
    fobj.write(d)
```

that would give you a file containing

```
{
    "Query": "Pages",
    "items": [
        {
            "url": "https://stackoverflow.com/",
            "title": "Stackoverflow",
            "description": "Stack Overflow is the largest"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page",
            "title": "Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia",
            "description": "Main page"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that length of all the lists are same (which they need to be for this to work)

```py
items = []
urls=["https://stackoverflow.com/", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"]
Title=["https://stackoverflow.com/", "Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia"]
Description=["Stack Overflow is the largest","Main page"]

for index in range(len(urls)):
    items.append({"url" : url[index],
                     "Title" : Title[index],
                     "Description" : Description[index]
                     )
```

This should give you the `items` array in required format.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thanks a lot, will look into that.